# Can you find the fingerprint type(ex. index finger, middle finger etc.) using the fingerprint sensor on Android?

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

Is it possible to recognise the fingerprint type(index, middle, thumb etc) by using the fingerprint sensor API? Does android lets you access the fingerprint data for comparison with other fingerprint types and let's you determine the type of the finger?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Android currently does not provide an API to detect which finger has been used to authenticate.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will the upcoming improved biometric api in android P would change things?

Comment: The new biometric API enables usage of fingerprint, face and iris of the eye for authentication purposes. The API does not mention the ability to detect the finger.